# CRUD Operations on Identity and custom table relationship using entity framework core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity, ef-core-2.0

I have the following dbcontext class:

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
    : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Initiative> initiatives { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers {get; set;}
}
```

AppUsers have a one to many relationship with initiave like so:

```
public List<Initiative> user_initiatives_created;
```

Initiative have a navigation property defined like so:

```
public string UserId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public AppUser User { get; set; }
```

I am trying to create an initiative object and store it to database with the following code which throws an object null reference exception:

```
Initiative i = new Initiative(init_model);
AppUser user = await _dbContext.AppUsers.FindAsync(_usermgr.GetUserId(HttpContext.User));
i.User = user;
i.UserId = _usermgr.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
user.user_initiatives_created.Add(i); //throws exception
_dbContext.initiatives.Add(i);
_dbContext.AppUsers.Update(user);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I think this is because `i.Id` is still 0 and hence could not be added to the database. But this object wont be assigned an id unless it is EF Core assigns an Id after it `SaveChanges()`.

What is the best way to create the initiative table and simultaneously updating the user table?

Comment: can i see the class definition for `AppUser`?

Comment: @MikeCorcoran The AppUser class had a problem that i did not add getters and setters to the `user_initiatives_created` property. The problem is solved by @Nikolay 's solution.

Comment: yes, this is what i was getting at and wanted to verify. glad you resolved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to change both User and Initiative. it should work, if you leave only the following code:

```
Initiative i = new Initiative(init_model);
i.UserId = _usermgr.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
_dbContext.initiatives.Add(i);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

"Null reference exception" is thrown because your user.user_initiatives_created property is null. There are more errors in database application architecture.

Comment: Yes this works. And yes, I forgot to add getters and setters to `user_initiatives_created` property.
 How do the `AppUser.Initiatives` get populated then? Does EF core do it automatically behind the scenes?

Comment: public DbSet<Initiative> initiatives { get; set; }

Relations in EF Core handled by navigation properties. The above property in User table is navigation property which will be used to get related entity. (in this case it is collection of initiative) 

EF Core can load data in three different methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

When you add an initiative with userId as a foreign key. Then you can access the related user from initiative object and vice versa.